# <Transactional Replication> Data is not getting updated in subscriber

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, transactional-replication

I was testing Transactional Replication on my machine before setting up on PROD but when I do a `UPDATE` that update is not getting propagated to the subscriber and when I see the replication monitor I see a lots of error message saying `can't drop table abc cause it's being used for replication`.

Any idea what could be going wrong? Please let me know.

I am using

SQL Server 2008 R2
Windows Server 2008(OS)

Replicating on the same machine (Publisher and Subscriber are on the same machine).

Also, I am testing with a simple UPDATE statement like `UPDATE abc set col1='something' where col1='someotherthing'`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the UPDATE statement is causing the error message "can't drop table abc because it's being used for replication".  It's possible that a previous transaction is still  open that attempted to drop abc table.  This could be blocking the update statement.  Try running sp_who and querying sys.dm_tran_locks to see if there are any blocking transactions.

gl.